# Can I artificially limit the Columnstore cache size in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, columnstore

I am trying to evaluate the potential performance of a data science workload on a large-ish dataset (~200GB).  We have had excellent results using columnstore indexes in SQL Server 2017.

However, the business is interested in cost savings, and I have pointed out to them that columnstore indexes are now available in Standard Edition, albeit with a memory limit of 32GB.  It's possible to determine the current memory use by looking at DMV *sys.dm_column_store_object_pool*

I would like to know if it's possible to limit the columnstore-dedicated RAM allocation to evaluate how the workload performance changes.

I'm aware that it's possible to limit the total RAM usage in SQL Server, but that will not provide a real indication of the very specific columnstore limits.

I should clarify that since we are currently using Developer Edition, there are no resource limits at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a solution to this (prompted by David Brownie's answer above).
We are testing on CentOS, and SQL Server has a config tool which lets you change the edition:

/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf

I have changed the edition temporarily to Standard, and will change back to Developer after the performance benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MSDN license you can download and install SQL Server Standard Edition for Dev/Test.

Otherwise you can use an Azure Pay-As-You-Go instance for testing.  See eg

[SQL Server 2017 Standard on Windows Server 2016](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.SQLServer2017StandardonWindowsServer2016?tab=Overview)